# Align buttons horizontally at bottom, when text amount is different

Tags: html, css

[Button problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzsU8.png)

Look at the image above. What's the best way to align the 3 buttons at the bottom? They should be displayed in line, and not be ruled by the amount of text above.

Comment: Add min-height: 250px; in text content section above button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have placed your "login" and "register" blocks inside two `<div>` or `<span>` blocks separately and colored the backgrounds in one color. If then, buttons inside these two blocks can be aligned straight by setting css properties `position` to `absolute` and `bottom` to the height that will keep them inline with the first button. That means if you want to get them to align with the first button, try setting different values until the other two buttons elevate up to that level.
Hope this helps